# How can I disable the window icon context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, titlebar

If you left click on the top left icon in a window's title bar a context menu comes up (Restore, Move, Size, etc.)

How can I disable the menu?  My apps Ribbon application button overlaps that area and it comes up sometimes while pressing the button.

IconVisibility="Collapsed" or IconVisibility="Hidden" hides the icon but the click event is still triggered.

Comment: It's the Office UI ribbon. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Office 07 skin (as most of the examples around on the net use), this is a bug. You may have also noticed the hit detection for the Orb is a bit dodgy.

When I was developing our UI, I was forced to change skin because I found the Office 07 skin too buggy.

My recommendation, as Microsoft has changed the Office 2010 ribbon to look like this:
[Office 2010 ribbon http://pakblogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/2010-21.png](http://pakblogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/2010-21.png)

is to use the base skin, which looks essentially the same. Then you can remove the icon like normal if you wish.

EDIT: To use the base skin, just remove the code in the XAML that sets the skin.

This is the pitfall of using the CTP, there is bugs and there isn't much you can do about it

Comment: The key point being that the WPF ribbon is only a CTP. The Win32 one is considerably more stable, but is not leveraged at all for the WPF version. Keep an eye out for newer releases.